# SharePoint JSOM: get SPFolder custom field value

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-clientobject

We have

1. a SharePoint 2013 document library
2. a custom content type added to the library, based on standard "Folder" content type; a new "DisplayName" text field added to the content type
3. a few folders of that custom content type were created in the document library

I try to make a JavaScript control to visualize folder structure from the library. But I can't get the custom "DisplayName" field value

```
this.clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

var web = this.clientContext.get_web();
this.clientContext.load(web);

this.clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function(sender, args) {

    for (var i = 0; i < this.topLevelFoldersUrl.length; i++) {

        var contextParams = {};

        contextParams.folderUrl = web.get_serverRelativeUrl() + "/" + this.topLevelFoldersUrl[i];

        // folder
        contextParams.topLevelFolder = web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(contextParams.folderUrl);
        this.clientContext.load(contextParams.topLevelFolder, 'Include(DisplayName)');

        // folder list item
        contextParams.folderListItem = contextParams.topLevelFolder.get_listItemAllFields();
        this.clientContext.load(contextParams.folderListItem);

        // subfolders
        contextParams.folderCollection = contextParams.topLevelFolder.get_folders();
        this.clientContext.load(contextParams.folderCollection);

        this.clientContext.executeQueryAsync(

            function (sender, args) {

                var folderName = contextParams.topLevelFolder.get_name();

                // EXCEPTION goes here: "property has not been initialized"
                var folderDisplayName = contextParams.folderListItem.get_item("DisplayName");

                // visualization code...

            },
            this.onQueryFailed
        );
    }
}, this.onQueryFailed);
```

Is there a special technique to get folder custom fields? I've googled all the code samples to get list items and their custom fields, but the samples don't work in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"DisplayName" seems to be a reserved identifier in SharePoint 2013 JSOM. After changing field's name to "ShownName" my code worked:

```
this.clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

var web = this.clientContext.get_web();
this.clientContext.load(web);

this.clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function (sender, args) {

    for (var i = 0; i < this.topLevelFoldersUrl.length; i++) {

        var contextParams = {};

        contextParams.folderUrl = web.get_serverRelativeUrl() + "/" + this.topLevelFoldersUrl[i];

        contextParams.topLevelFolder = web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(contextParams.folderUrl);
        this.clientContext.load(contextParams.topLevelFolder);

        contextParams.folderListItem = contextParams.topLevelFolder.get_listItemAllFields();
        this.clientContext.load(contextParams.folderListItem, 'ShownName');

        contextParams.folderCollection = contextParams.topLevelFolder.get_folders();
        this.clientContext.load(contextParams.folderCollection);                        

        this.clientContext.executeQueryAsync(

            function(sender, args) {

                var folderName = folder.get_name(); 
                var folderDisplayName = folderItem.get_item("ShownName");

                // visualization code...
            },
            this.onQueryFailed
        );
    }
}, this.onQueryFailed);
```